# garage breaker keeps tripping

Tags: switch, circuit-breaker, garage

I tried to upload a pic but the it says the size is too large So my breaker tripped the other day when I plugged in a set of lights. I unplugged them reset the breaker and the switch/plug combo I had the lights plugged into on. The breaker tripped again (with no lights plugged in) Reset the breaker and tried the front lights on the garage (didn't trip) and the garage door works. So I decided I needed to replace the switch/plug combo. I replaced them and now the other switch for the front lights trips the breaker also but the garage door still works fine. It's a 15 amp breaker and I have made sure to unplug everything to do the breaker tests. Any ideas? might it be a bad breaker?

Comment: What kind of breaker do you have? Is it a standard breaker, or is it a GFCI or AFCI? I doubt it's a bad breaker. Have you changed anything with the wiring?

Comment: Upload the pic to imgur.com (you don’t need to create an acct there.. just upload now) then put the link here.  Someone with more rep will help get it edited into your question.

Comment: The way I was told to check a breaker many years ago, is to see how much pressure it takes to push the switch over to the tripped position under low/no load condition. It should take a good amount of force to trip it. If it pops over with just a light touch, then you might have a bad breaker.

Comment: @Norm that may have one time been a good indicator for a specific brand of breakers.  Today it’s junk advice, most circuit breaker handles move with feather touch just about now.